# how weblogic connection with Database work

Tags: database-connection, weblogic

I have a Weblogic server that connects to a database, how can i test the connection between them in the command line?
Is there any command I can use to see if they have a connection between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a very basic test of the connection from the machine that weblogic is running on to your database by using `telnet <database server address> <database port>`.  Usually a blank return prompt means a successful connection.

Please note that this does not really test the connection from your weblogic application server but rather from the machine it is running on.  I know you mentioned a command line test but if you have access to the weblogic console a better test would be to initiate a test from the database monitoring tab.